# ImportError: No module named bs4 scraping hub

Tags: python

```
Packing version 1.0
Deploying to Scrapy Cloud project "316316"
Deploy log last 30 lines:
    _get_apisettings, commands_module='sh_scrapy.commands')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 148, in _run_usercode
    _run(args, settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 103, in _run
    _run_scrapy(args, settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 111, in _run_scrapy
    execute(settings=settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 149, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 251, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 137, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 338, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 61, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 47, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/app/__main__.egg/niceprice/spiders/forever.py", line 11, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bs4
{"message": "shub-image-info exit code: 1", "details": null, "error": "image_info_error"}
```

Hello, I wrote a scrapy spider, and I am trying to deploy onto scraping hub, I needed to use BeautifulSoup to handle broken HTML parts, I am getting the following error when deploying.

Comment: What command did you run to get this error?

Comment: I don't know anything about scrapy hu, but I searched a bit and found this: https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000200400-deploying-python-dependencies-for-your-projects-in-scrapy-cloud You need to create a **`requirements.txt`** file to deploy

Comment: @curusarn I used `shub login` then `shub deploy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [support page on scrapinghub.com](https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000200400-deploying-python-dependencies-for-your-projects-in-scrapy-cloud):

> Here's what you have to do in order to deploy python dependencies for
>   your projects:
>
> 1. create a requirements.txt file containing your extra dependencies in your project's root folder
> 2. set that file as the requirements value in your project's scrapinghub.yml configuration file
> 3. deploy your project with the dependencies
>
> **1. Creating the requirements.txt file**
>
> This is a regular text file where you list the Python packages that
>   your project depends on, one package per line. For example:
>
> ```
> js2xml==0.2.1 
> extruct==0.1.0 
> requests==2.6.0
> ```
>
> You should always pin
>   down the specific versions for each of your dependencies, as we did in
>   the example above. By doing this, you avoid the trouble of getting
>   your spiders broken due to unexpected upgrades.
>
> **2. Configuring your dependencies on scrapinghub.yml**
>
> After creating the requirements file, add the requirements setting to
>   scrapinghub.yml and point it to your project's requirements.txt path:
>
> ```
> projects:
>    default: 12345 
> requirements:
>    file: requirements.txt
> ```
>
> Note: if there's no scrapinghub.yml file in your project folder, you
>   should run shub deploy once to generate it.
>
> **3. Deploying your project**
>
> Now that you've set your project dependencies, it's time to deploy
>   your project. Just run a regular shub deploy and then you should be
>   able to use your spiders with extra dependencies in Scrapy Cloud.
>
> `$ shub deploy`

Comment: @madboy: Here's how: https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000200387-deploying-python-3-spiders-to-scrapy-cloud